# How to change the appearing text on a button

Tags: c#

What I need to do is change the text on a button but in a more general way. For example I would like to define exactly the position of each character( and not the position of the whole sentence).

Comment: what do you mean by defining the position of each character? what have you done so far?

Comment: I have found a way to change the position of a sentence such "I am a button", but I do not want that. Think more of letters appearing in a way that seems to have been thrown on the button and have stuck on it.

Comment: We cant read you mind, show us exactly what you mean as there is no throw font feature

Comment: Also, thinking about this for a second, maybe there is a custom font that does this

Comment: You can use WPF to do what you want. Or you can use image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found out, there is a `TextAlign` Property that you can use to align where the text appears, but for very custom ways of positioning there is not (and of course can not be) properties, but however you can use `Paint` event of the button to draw the text as you like:

```
    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 14, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Button btn = ((Button)sender);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(btn.Text[0].ToString(), f, new SolidBrush(Color.Red), new Point(10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(btn.Text.Substring(1), f, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new Point(22, 15));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some JavaScript and JQuery for customizing the look.  You can make them work with your C# / ASP.NET project. Here's an example:

First, in your .aspx file, make a container for your fancy custom button (see MyCustomBtn below).

Also have a regular submit button that runs at the server level (MySubmitBtn), but hide it using CSS; display:none;

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
...
<div id="MyCustomBtn"> ... </div>
...
<div style="display:none;">
<asp:Button ID="MySubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="MySubmitBtn_Click" />
</div>
...
</form>
```

Next, make sure to include JQuery in your project.

You can download it from the official site here: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

And save this file in your project. Then refer to it in the head of your .aspx page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\your\Path\jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then include this code to handle any clicks on MyCustomBtn to cause a click on the MySubmitBtn as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#MyCustomBtn").click(function () {
        $("#MySubmitBtn").click();
    });

    ...

});
```

You can then use CSS, HTML, JavaScript, JQuery, and your imagination to customize MyCustomBtn however you wish.

Here's the full (rough) code for this example. There are much better ways to write all of this, but this should help give you an idea.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\your\Path\jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    /* clearfix credit goes to http://www.mikepadgett.com/technology/technical/alternative-to-the-pie-clearfix-hack/ */
    .clearfix:after 
    {
        clear: both; 
        content: "."; 
        display: block; 
        height: 0; 
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .clearfix 
    {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
    * html .clearfix {height: 1%;}
    .clearfix {display: block;}
    /* End hide from IE-mac */

    .customButtonStyle
    {
        background: #00C;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .floatLeft
    {
        float: left;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div id="MyCustomBtn"> 
    <div class="clearfix customButtonStyle">
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #f99;padding: 1px 4px 30px 2px'>C</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #8f9;padding: 30px 2px 1px 2px'>l</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #fa0;padding: 15px 2px 16px 2px'>i</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #290;padding: 10px 4px 21px 2px'>c</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #fff;padding: 1px 2px 30px 2px'>k</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #2f9;padding: 21px 4px 10px 4px'>M</div>
        <div class="floatLeft" style='color: #f29;padding: 30px 2px 1px 2px'>e</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="display:none;">
    <asp:Button ID="MySubmitBtn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="MySubmitBtn_Click" />
</div>

</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#MyCustomBtn").click(function () {
            $("#MySubmitBtn").click();
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```